# Trying to write contents of lists into xml

Tags: python-3.x, xml, elementtree

I have 3 lists which are the same length and I am trying to write them into a xml file as follows:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

title_list = ['title1', 'title2', 'title3']
date_list = ['date1', 'date2', 'date3']
text_list = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3']

book = ET.Element('book')
for e in zip(title_list, date_list, text_list):

    book = ET.Element('book')
    article = ET.SubElement(book, 'article')
    title = ET.SubElement(article, 'title')
    date = ET.SubElement(article, 'date')
    text = ET.SubElement(article, 'text')

    title.text = e[0]
    date.text = e[1]
    text.text = e[2]


tree_out = ET.ElementTree(book)
tree_out.write('test.xml')
```

my output ('pretty printed' in oxygen):

```
<book>
    <article>
        <title>title3</title>
        <date>date3</date>
        <text>text3</text>
    </article>
</book>
```

but I would like to have:

```
<book>
    <article>
        <title>title1</title>
        <date>date1</date>
        <text>text1</text>
    </article>
    <article>
        <title>title2</title>
        <date>date2</date>
        <text>text2</text>
    </article>
    <article>
        <title>title3</title>
        <date>date3</date>
        <text>text3</text>
    </article>
</book>
```

How can I get the whole output? I've been reading a lot on here but nothing works for me. Please explain it in simple terms, as I'm pretty new to this library and xml in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `for` loop, you redefine `book` so it's getting overwritten with each iteration.

Remove that and you should get the results you're looking for...

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

title_list = ['title1', 'title2', 'title3']
date_list = ['date1', 'date2', 'date3']
text_list = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3']

book = ET.Element('book')
for e in zip(title_list, date_list, text_list):

    # book = ET.Element('book')  # <-- REMOVE THIS LINE
    article = ET.SubElement(book, 'article')
    title = ET.SubElement(article, 'title')
    date = ET.SubElement(article, 'date')
    text = ET.SubElement(article, 'text')

    title.text = e[0]
    date.text = e[1]
    text.text = e[2]

tree_out = ET.ElementTree(book)
tree_out.write('test.xml')
```